# How to make Google Sheet remember latest known valid value

Tags: api, caching, google-sheets

I am using a history tracking system for statistics and monitoring.
Some data is pulled with API. Some Data is not.
However, sometimes, or actually everyday, there are problems pulling data from the API, which results in #ERROR! and useless reports. One or more #ERROR!´s corrupts all the totals and calculations.
However, it is not important that I always have 100% updated data from API, a few hours or even days delay is no problem, so I have been looking for weeks to find a solution to remember or cache the latest known valid value from where I would be able to pulls data with IFERROR function.

I was hoping for something like `=IFERROR(A1, CACHE)` - formula...

Does this feature exist and how to use it ?

Comment: there is no cache feature in google sheets. you can either build it via scripts or look it up in history revision

Comment: History would break with the principle of autorisation, also, there are hundreds of  #ERROR!´s - it would be a full time job to use history feature. There must be some trick to copy and remember the last numeric valid value, and then use it when/if #ERROR!´s occur.

Comment: I think you can try to put your last valid value to your another Column, just an idea. For example, each time data change you take from col A to col X just for valid value, the others ini col X keep the last valid value

Comment: Is it possible to take from Col a til Col X , each time data change, with valid data (numeric), and do it automatically?